# Accessing consecutive members with a single pointer

Tags: c++

I want to access continuously declared member arrays of the same type with a single pointer.

So for [**example**](http://ideone.com/WfA2bd) say I have :

```
struct S 
{
    double m1[2];
    double m2[2]; 
}

int main()
{
    S obj; 
    double *sp = obj.m1;

    // Code that maybe unsafe !!
    for (int i(0); i < 4; ++i)
        *(sp++) = i; // *

    return 0;
}
```

**Under what circumstances is line (*) problematic ?**

<sup>I know there's for sure a problem when virtual functions are present but I need a more structured answer than my assumptions</sup>

Comment: Most compilers give you some sort of mechanism for controlling how members are aligned within structs (for example, `#pragma pack(...)` in Microsoft's). If you use these to guarantee no padding will be inserted between the two double arrays, you'll be ok.

Comment: why do you *want* to write code that is *maybe unsafe*, since you know it already?

Comment: @Sigismondo It's code that was being used in legacy C files, which I'm turning into C++ and I'm having doubdts concerning what will happen when the memory model changes or whether we'll have problem scaling. Discarding the whole lot is quite some work and I want to see if it's avoidable.

Comment: I see - in this case you could write a simple test (is `m1+2 == m2` ?) that just check about the consistency among OS'es, compiler versions and fails in case the assumption that is correct with current typical compilers, will stop being in some future release. Add it to your build and you should be safe from run-time errors... *maybe* :)

Comment: @Sigismondo That's a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard makes certain guarantees about the layout of "plain old data" (or in C++11, standard layout) types.  For the most part, these inherit from how C treated such data.

What follows only applies to "plain old data"/"standard layout" structures and data.

If you have two structs with the same initial order and type of arguments, casting a pointer to one to a pointer to the other and accessing their common initial prefix is valid, and will access the corresponding field.  This is known as "layout compatible".  This also applies if you have a structure X and a structure Y, and X is the first element of the structure Y -- a pointer to Y can be cast to a pointer to X, and it will access the fields of the X substructure in Y.

Now, while it is a common assumption, I am unaware of a requirement of either C or C++ that an array and a structure starting with fields of the same type and count are layout compatible with an array.

Your case is somewhat similar, in that we have two arrays adjacent to each other in a structure, and you are treating it as one large array of size equal to the sum of those two arrays size.  It is a relatively common and safe assumption that it works, but I am unaware of a guarantee in the standard that it actually works.

In this kind of undefined behavior, you have to examine your particular compilers guarantees (de facto or explicit) about layout of plain old data/standard layout data, as the C++ standard does not guarantee your code does what you want it to do.

Comment: This (kind of) justifies me stopping people from adding constructors to these structs once they've been "ported" to C++. I guess losing PODness will cause even more problems to such delinquent uses.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou "standard layout" does not care about constructors.  C++11 gives (most) POD guarantees to "standard layout" structures, at least with regards to data layout.  Its standardization in C++11 was simply a guarantee of what every (almost every?) compiler already did, rather than a change in how compilers behave, so it is even safe in every C++03 compiler I know about.

Answer (score 3):

You can be sure that the members of the struct are stored in a contiguos block of bytes, in the order they appear. Besides, the elements of the arrays are contiguous. So, it seems that everything is fine.
The problem here is that there is no standard way of knowing if there is padding bytes between consecutive members in the struct.
So, it is unsafe to assume that there is not padding bytes at all.

If you can be plenty sure, for some particular reason, that there are not padding bytes, then the 4 `double` elements will be contiguous, as you want.

Comment: I was under the impression that padding bytes can only occur between members of different type

Comment: Solution : add one or more `static_assert`'s so you know when it blows up.

Comment: In general allignment is the reason behind the way the compiler choose to add padding bytes or not. Now, think about 2 members having 11 bytes each, both of the same type. I think they will not be contiguous in memory. But, in any case, it's just guessing, because is not standard. As **dlf** pointed out in his comment, the "packing" options of the compiler could give you more certainty. I think you ould have to investigate these compiler **packing** options or related #pragma's.